# Change target framework in VB.NET console app

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I created a VB Console app and it defaulted to .NET 4 but I need it to be .NET 3.5. I've been looking but all the references I find say to change it on the 'Compile' tab in properties but I don't have a compile tab or anything else that lets me change the target framework.

Any ideas other than recreating the project?

**Note: I'm using VS2010 Ultimate**

Update: added screen shot

[image]

Comment: Right click on the project, hit Properties, a window opens up, hit the Application tab (lhs), Target Framework is right there.

Comment: @Will nope. See my screen shot.

Comment: Have you seen this before?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex6a2fad.aspx  Sounds like something might be hosed on your machine.  If you create a new console app is the compile tab there?

Comment: Tools + Options, Import/Export, Reset.  Might work.

Comment: @Jeff nope. if I create a new 3.5 project it isn't there either.

Comment: @Will that's why I stick to C#...

Comment: @DustinDavis - On my machine for any VB.Net Console apps the compile tab is there.  I'm thinking it might be your install.  Have you tried any of the resets mentioned above?

Comment: @Jeff V Nope, didn't help. I tried /safemode too, but it's a no go. I'll try /reset a bit later as i'm wanting to go back to default color scheme anyway.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you sure you are right clicking the project, then clicking Properties? For me in the properties window there is a `Compile` tab on the left side (under `Application`), and there is an option to change the target under `Advanced Compile Options...`.

Comment: You could try switching all the references to the 3.5 ones and editing the project file directly, although I'm not sure if that would work completely.

Comment: I thought about that but I think i'm just gonna create a new proj.

Answer (score 1):

In vs2010 you goto PROJECT ---> SLN Name properties --> COMPILE ---> ADVANCED COMPILE OPTIONS(BOTTOM).   Now Reverting it to 3.5 is something that as far as I know is something you can't do, atleast not easily or advised.  Obviously upgrading from say a 2.0 to a 3.5 or 4.0 framework is easy as the step's above.  Your best bet is unfortunately to create a new project in the 3.5 framework.

Answer (score 0):

Project/Properties/Compile/Advanced Compile Options

[image]